# How to access MailItem from UserControl?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, outlook-2010

hey guys, i have a usercontrol within the default email compose form, I want to get the mailitem of that window.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are composing an email, you must be in an Outlook Inspector.  So you would have code like this:

```
Inspector inspector = window as Inspector;
MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
```

Comment: i'm puzzling over how to get 'window' within the Load event handler of a CustomTaskPane :(

there isnt a this.context or anything, object sender is the CustomTaskPane itself, and EventArgs e doesn't contain much.

Comment: You have to handle the Inspectors.NewInspector event. The corresponding event handler has an Inspector (the window) as an argument. You need to keep track of that Inspector when you create the CustomTaskPane so that you can use the Inspector after the window is loaded to get your MailItem.

Comment: that would work in normal scenarios, but I have a further problem that the form needs to be invoked from outside of outlook. When you invoke the compose email form from outside outlook, NewInspector event will not fire :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some type of CheckBox or RadioButton control on your user UserControl you could utilize the ActiveInspector to get a hold of the mailItem:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
namespace My_Outlook_Plugin
{
     public partial class UserControl_Classification : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl_Classification()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void UserControl_Classification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
            if (inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
                    //Do something with mailItem
                    
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
                }          
         }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

Also, this is a really good explanation on setting up a wrapper which you need to to to track each potential mailItem window the the user might open and dispose of it properly  - [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2019#create-the-project)